# What does a(1, a(2, :)) do for a logical matrix a in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to understand some Matlab code. One line goes `a(1, a(2, :))`, where `a` is a logical matrix. The result of this line is a single logical value. I wonder what this line does?

Answer (score 1):

The code selects the entries in the first row of `a` wherever the second row of `a` is equal to `1`.

In MATLAB, when you index with a number like `a(1, [2,3,4])` you get the second, third, and fourth entry in the first row of `a`. When you use a logical, it pulls out entries that are equal to `1` only so the previous command is equal to `a(1, logical([0 1 1 1]))` because the second, third, and fourth entry in in the index are equal to `1`. Therefore, the command `a(1, find(a(2,:)))` is equivalent to `a(1, a(2, :))`.